# How to add a view to the top of a linear layout in code?

Tags: java, android, view, admob, android-linearlayout

I need to add an admob adview to a linear layout in code but I need to insert it at the top of the layout, not the bottom.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use:

> public void addView (View child, int index) Since: API Level 1
>
> Adds a child view. If no layout parameters are already set on the
>   child, the default parameters for this ViewGroup are set on the child.
>   Parameters child  the child view to add index     the position at which
>   to add the child See Also

So

```
yourLayout.addView(yourView, 0);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)

Comment: Thank you man, i was a bit confused because i wanted to implement it in some big code, so i was hesitating, you made things clear.

Comment: But that implies that you override item 0?

Comment: @LambertoBasti No, it is inserted, meaning your old view at 0 moves to index 1

Comment: OMG, thought it was much harder.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do it as well, but using only `LinearLayout` it always added the view at the bottom, no matter which `index` I passed to `addView`.

I wrapped the `LinearLayout` in a `RelativeLayout`, then you do that:

```
relativeLayout.addView(adView);
adView.setId(View.generateViewId());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
llParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
```

That is working for me.