# android How to add view at start of layout?

Tags: android, view

My question is simple. I have a linearlayout. It has some child views. Now I want to add a view at the start of the child. Means in normal addView(view), the view s added at the end of the layout. But I want to add it at start, at first position. Any idea...???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a view to the top of a linear layout in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270224/how-to-add-a-view-to-the-top-of-a-linear-layout-in-code)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [`addView (View child, int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) with index = 0

Comment: It would be just addView(View child)

Comment: i did with -1 and it is working. I didn't try addView(View child)

Comment: @Muneeb Mirza
If you look inside android's ViewGroup Class you can see the below code:

if (index < 0) {
        index = mChildrenCount;
    }
So, if you put number less then 0 it been replaced with the size of all the childrens -> that means on the bottom :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider exploring the index argument of the `addView` method in parent class ViewGroup, Specifically `addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`. This method adds a View to the parent layout with the params defined, the index acts as a preference or rather point of insertion of the view in the layout.

Answer (score -2):

create a list of views, add your view to it and then add all views from layout to that list, remove all views from layout and add all views from your list

Comment: This will layout the views and parent view everytime. It consumes too much memory and will have performance issues.