# Is index important in addView()?

Tags: android, view

I can't understand the function of `index` in `addView(View child, int index)` of a `ViewGroup`.
What's the `index` for? Can be `index` negative value? Does it affect to the `layout` or the way to display the `view`?
I have tested the code with and without `index` and I can't see the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point of the index attribute is to allow you change the order of views.

Let's say you have a massive list of views, and want to suddenly put one at the very top. If you specify that view's index as 0, it will be the first to display in the layout.

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) talks briefly about this.

A previous SO question shows the practical use for this: [Android: How to add view at start of layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443480/android-how-to-add-view-at-start-of-layout).

Unless you really need to specify a position for the view, just use `addView(view)`.

Comment: So, the order and position means Z-order? I mean, which view is above another?

Comment: @Fran You could say that. It's like the order in which they're displayed. 0 is before 1, and 5 is after 4 in the display order. 0 will be at the top (or left), and the highest number at the bottom (or right).

Comment: @JosephBoyle AddView(view) without index does not work., Try it with LinearLayout. It is one of those things that makes you wonder what a piece of shit android is.

Answer (score 0):

After testing,I found that the index represent the order of view to be draw.
eg:
index=0 means that this view will be the first view to be drawn on the canvas, instead of the first view  to be shown because index=1 or bigger might cover this view.