# Adding one layout on top of another programatically

Tags: android, layout

I've got a button that when tapped, creates a RelativeLayout with simple Views like text in it. They're all to be contained in a vertical linear layout.

When tapping in succession, multiple relative layouts get created, with the latest layout created stacked below the previous one. I would, however, like to reverse this order - the latest layout gets stacked ABOVE the previous one.

Relative layouts don't have attributes like `layout_below` etc, however. The only messy way I can do this is with a grid layout, with the latest ones having a row number less than the previous one. Again, this is messy and consumes unnecessarily memory by preloading a bunch of invisible rows.

Does anyone have an elegant way of doing this? I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Are you using `.addView(View view)` to add views to your layout? If yes, you can use `addView(View view, int index)`, with index 0 to add it to the top.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was completely unaware that that parameter existed. It works as I intend it to now. Go ahead and answer the question, I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: You are more than welcome. The question will maybe be closed, because it is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443480/android-how-to-add-view-at-start-of-layout) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `addView(View view)` to inflate views to your layout, you can use

```
addView(View child, int index)
```

with index 0 to add it to the top.