# android studio addview is adding the first 2 views normally but then it starts adding them at random location

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout-inflater

here is the code I am using to inflate and add views:

```
         public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert inflater != null;
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_rooms, null);
    // Add the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

}
```

Here is the layout I am inflating:

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="add another room"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="152dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img_del"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onDelete"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

My problem here is that When I press the add button it adds the first 2 views normally but then when I press it a third time it adds a new view between the old 2, now this is not a problem as I can manage with it but its still bothering me,  so how can I fix such behavior,I would like to make the new views to always be created on top while the old ones go below.

here is the code for the parent container:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Did you try to add a rowView without atIndex? Example `parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView)`.

Comment: +Liem Vo after working on it for an hour I found the error, its this line parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1); after I replaced  parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1 with a constant number it worked fine, I don't know why its doing this with getchildcount since its returning the same values as the constant.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270274/2280692), to add the view to the top of LinearLayout you should pass `0` as the index of the child view being added in addView(View childView, int index);

So, use: `parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, 0);`

Hope it works!

Comment: but the ID is supposed to be dynamic nm I fixed it just had to replace parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1 with a constant and every time a view gets added it gets incremented, maybe  parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1 has a bug as its returning the same value as the constant.

Comment: This parameter is the index in which you want the view to be added, not it's ID. It specifies **in which position** your view should be added. So, if you have one child added and adds the second with index 0, the first child will be moved to index 1 (below the recently added child). Check the constant you are using. Maybe it's value is 0?